# How to create CD with auto run that opens full screen browser?

Tags: windows, browser, fullscreen, autoplay

I have a CD with presentation made in HTML format (there are reasons for that). AutoPlay on Windows should open default browser and display presentation in full screen mode.
How to achieve that?

Comment: `iexplore -k presentation.html` is the best thing I came up with, but it's kiosk mode, not full screen and it opens IE, not default browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest method that worked for me was http://www.menubox.com/ launcher. There is one drawback  - it uses integrated windows browser component instead of default browser and it ain't free.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible modes to create a cd/dvd that will autorun to open the html file in a full screen mode.

1) Using a windows shell to maximize it.
2) Using a JavaScript

1)**Using Windows Shell Method**:

The following autorun.inf file invokes the command processor to start a full screen browser on the html file "index.htm":

```
[autorun]
open=command /c start /max index.htm
```

Note: Use of "command" & "start" restrict this to machines running Windows OS. So this won't be supported on other platforms.

2) **Using a JavaScript**

The following .inf file will invoke the browser:

```
[autorun]
ShellExecute=index.htm
```

now place the following script between Here goes your script tags :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (document.all || document.layers)
{
  window.moveTo(0,0);
  window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth,screen.availHeight)
} else if (window.screen) {
  window.moveTo(0,0);
  window.outerHeight = screen.availHeight;
  window.outerWidth = screen.availWidth;
}
//-->
```

Note: script wont maximize your window, it will just resize the browser window. This will run on all platforms.

Comment: Theese two methods doesn't open window in fullscreen, they just maximize browser window.

Comment: @Stancell Did you read my note?

Comment: _There are 2 possible modes to create a cd/dvd that will autorun to open the html file in a full screen mode._ @V413HAV: That was misleading, because none of your specified methods open window in full screen mode.